# Call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback (Event handler system)

Tags: php, function, handler

I'm trying to make a system which handles supplied data and calls the functions assigned to them in an array with addHandler().

Code:

```
class Test {

    public $arrHandlers = array();

    public function addHandler($action, $function) {
        $this->arrHandlers[$action] = $function;
    }

    public function handleData($data) {
        $data   = explode("/", $data);
        $action = array_shift($data);
        if(isset($this->arrHandlers[$action])) {
            call_user_func_array($this->arrhandlers[$action], array($data));
        }
    }
}

function testFunc() {
    echo implode(" ", func_get_args());
}

$obj  = new Test();
$data = "egg/I/like/cheese";
$obj->addHandler("egg", "testFunc");
$obj->handleData($data);
```

What it outputs:

```
Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, no array or string given on line 13
```

What I want it to output:

```
I like cheese
```

Comment: `$this->arrHandlers != $this->arrhandlers`. Do you have `E_NOTICE` displaying in your `error_reporting`? You should be getting an undefined property `Test::$arrhandlers` before the warning about `call_user_func_array()`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: hehe, yeah, including the NOTICE edit, once again in sync ;) I've just deleted mine, it felt way too much like a plain copy ;)

Comment: It should be `call_user_func_array($this->arrHandlers[$action], $data);`.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Can't believe I didn't notice that. Added `error_reporting(E_ALL)` and fixed the caps mistake. This is what I now get: `Notice: Array to string conversion on line 21
Array` . Line 21 is `echo implode(" ", func_get_args());`

Comment: Per @RocketHazmat's comment -that's the crux of it, after fixing the property casing on `arrHandlers`. I've tested it working with that implementation.

Comment: @RocketHazmat you should answer as that's the main issue.

Comment: @Will it's `$data`, not `array($data)` as the second arg to `call_user_func_array()`.

Answer (score 2):

Working code:

```
class Test {

    public $arrHandlers = array();

    public function addHandler($action, $function) {
        $this->arrHandlers[$action] = $function;
    }

    public function handleData($data) {
        $data   = explode("/", $data);
        $action = array_shift($data);
        if(isset($this->arrHandlers[$action])) {
            call_user_func_array($this->arrHandlers[$action], $data);
        }
    }
}

function testFunc() {
    echo implode(" ", func_get_args());
}

$obj  = new Test();
$data = "egg/I/like/cheese";
$obj->addHandler("egg", "testFunc");
$obj->handleData($data);
```

I put '`arrhandlers`' instead of '`arrHandlers`' and passed $data as '`array($data)`' instead of just '`$data`' to `call_user_func_array()`.